# newbie help with home page

Tags: homepage

Can someone show me a tip on how to remove these white spaces where these RED arrows are?

Am hoping to create a site that I can input in a blog format a quote and have a simple home page with some contact info on the bottom but I can figure out how to get rid of these white spaces. ANY tips appreciated in ANY of these steps!! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is usually the responsibility of your theme, so contact the theme author for support. (Theme support is out of scope here.)

You may be able to do some CSS tweaking with 'additional CSS' in the theme. Use the browser's Inspector (F9) to dig into that area to find the problem.